# Save pdf after the website user has filled it to database

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, adobe

I want to enable the user to fill a pdf or update some of the pre-filled information online and when they click 'finish', I would save that to the database with the updated info. I currently have it prefill the pdf and also allows the user to fill what they want in the database. How can I save the updated pdf after the user clicks the 'save' button.

[SOLVED] Another smaller question: how can I use the browser's pdf viewer in Process.start instead of using adobe? 
`var proc = Process.Start(@"cmd.exe ",@"/c " + filename)`

UPDATE: Any other services provide that functionality even if it is paid (Adobe) or something like it?

I am currently using Itextsharp to prefill the pdf and allow the user to fill the pdf.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(completedFilePath, FileMode.Create));
AcroFields acroFields = stamper.AcroFields;
acroFields.SetField("Text1.0.0", "hello");
stamper.Close();
reader.Close();
Process.Start(adobeReaderPath, completedFilePath);
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If your PC is configured to open PDF in a browser by default, you should be able to open a document instead of an application: `Process.Start(completedFilePath);`, otherwise you have to use browser's exe path as an application argument.

Comment: I had errors with that, but I just found another solution that I update my post to show. Thank you though!